# Group and count query in HQL

Tags: hql

I have HQL query that is giving me a headache and am hoping a friendly HQL wizard is out there who can help.

I think I'm trying to do something really simple but can't fathom it all.

I want to group and count some data to present it in a table and think I need a nested query of some sort but can't figure out the way to do it.

Basically I have a table (clients) which has relations to other tables that are used as lookups (clienttype) and (clientsex). The relationships is 1-m.  I want to group the clients by type and then have a column counting males, and another counting females. e.g

```
Type    | males | females

type A  | x     | x

type B  | x     | x
```

I can do the query just to get males or females but can't figure out how to get a second column.

Hope this makes sense, is possible and that someone is able to help.

Many thanks,

Craig

---

Query to get just males is:

```
SELECT a.clientStatus, COUNT(c.sex)

FROM

Tblclientstatus AS a RIGHT OUTER JOIN a.tblclients AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.tblsex AS c

WHERE c.sex = 'male'

GROUP BY a.clientStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a case when to add up "1" for each sex.
Something like this :

```
SELECT a.clientStatus, 
COUNT(
case when c.sex = 'male' then 1
        else 0 end
) as males,
COUNT(
case when c.sex = 'female' then 1
        else 0 end
) as females,
FROM
Tblclientstatus AS a RIGHT OUTER JOIN a.tblclients AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.tblsex AS c
GROUP BY a.clientStatus
```